# Sphere defined by Manhattan Distance

Tags: general-topology

I learned that (n + 1) points define a (n - 1)-dimension sphere in a n-dimension space **unless any of them are collinear**

However, this is using Euclidean distance as the "metric" or the "distance".

**Question: How many points are required to define a similar "sphere" using "Manhattan Distance", defined by**

$$d((x_{11},x_{12},...,x_{1n}),(x_{21},x_{22},...,x_{2n}))=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_{1i}-x_{2i}|$$

Sorry if the question is unclear.

Edit: Progress!

1) A Manhattan "circle" defined by a center and a distance is a rotated square.

2) 3 points do not uniquely define a rotated square when 3rd point is in the purple region.[image]

Comment: Define "define."  Do the center and one point on a surface define a sphere?  Why or why not?

Comment: I assume your points are all on the sphere itself, in particular none of them are the center. Is that correct? In this case you should really expect the answer to be the same; being able to prove it is really the issue.

Comment: For this question I am treating the "center" as just an ordinary point i.e. I don't know any information. Just like when using Euclidean distance, 3 points define a circle and 4 points define a sphere. But if I am considering center, a "center" and any point would define a sphere won't it

Comment: @GarethMa how do you obtain square rotated at an arbitrary angle as a "manhattan circle" I think the angle is fixed by your choice of coordinates.

Comment: A Manhattan circle in 2D is always a diamond shape, given by line segments with slope $\pm 1$, which intersect along the coordinate axes passing through the center. That intersection point is then a 90 degree angle bisected by the coordinate axes.

Comment: oh wait yes good point. If I am using a consistent coordinate axis (which I should) then the "opposite vertices" should form a line segment parallel to the axis should they